# Integrating Pagination iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My Project Link:

https://github.com/29satnam/AdvanceTableViewSearch.git

It's an advance table with search bar with all It's components i.e., ViewController, TableViewCell, Datasource, Object Handler and Cell initializer separate(in file) or dedicated written in Swift. I'm  using SwiftJSON to parse JSON data.

It queries data from deployd(backend service), database is quite large with 1k+ entries. So basically, I need to implement paging/pager, so that it doesn't query all data at once.

This is what deployd's docs says:

> $limit
>
> The $limit command allows you to limit the amount of objects that are
>   returned from a query. This is commonly used for paging, along with
>   $skip.
>
> // Return the top 10 scores {
>       $sort: {score: -1},
>       $limit: 10 }

Http version:

```
http://localhost:2403/something?$limit=25&$skip=25
```

I've tried MrAlek/PagedArray - a repo from github. It didn't work for me.
Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The provided url for the http version is pointing to your local computer and is not reachable for anyone else but you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You can change the URL. :) It's just an example.